# Lottie play the next 10 frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, frames, lottie

Is there a way to play the next 10 frames of a lottie animation on a click event?

This code plays specific frames (frames 0-20) and then stops:

```
anim.playSegments([0,20],true);
```

But I would like for a button to play the next 10 frames each time it is clicked. I could set up a counter, but did’t know if there was an easier way. Something like:

```
anim.play([++10],true);
```

Comment: Hey @Rj336, Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you also elaborate if do really need these `20` segments the first time as shown here: `anim.playSegments([0,20],true);` or is it just there to illustrate the use of the method and you only need the 10 successive frames on every click start from the first 10?

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I get lots of answers for other things here... but couldn’t find this one. I appreciate the help!
That’s right. The animation plays for 20 frames on load and then I want it to play the next (successive) 10 frames with each click of a button.

Comment: Then I think you can use a slight modification of the answer I have given below. Would you be able to do it yourself or should I edit my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable `startFrame` and then use that to remember where to start the next frame and play the next 10 frame from there. Just increment the `startFrame` variable by `10` on each click.

Your onload Code:

```
anim.playSegments([0,20],true);
```

Declare this outside of you onclick callback scope:

```
let startFrame = 20;
```

Then inside the click callback:

```
anim.playSegments([startFrame,startFrame+=10],true);
```

**EDIT**
I have Just changed `startFrame` initial value from 0 to 20 as the first 20 frames will be played on load.

Comment: I'm glad that helped! Enjoy coding!